# Error occurs during magento version upgrade from 2.3.4 to 2.3.6

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.4, magento-community

I have a codazon theme installed in my magento website , it works well in magento 2.3.4 , eversince i am upgraded to magento 2.3.6 , i am getting following error in my home page slider of codazon .

"Error filtering template: Type Error occurred when creating object: Codazon\ProductFilter\Block\Product\ProductsList\Interceptor"

After upgrade all my functionalities works well , but got this error in my home page slider .
So, anyone facing above error .
Thanks in advance

Comment: did you run compile command?

Comment: yes , already run all commands .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hey Mit,**

Please run this command

> sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Or if you migrated recently, that's mean you didn't install the theme properly, as in **Codazon** instruction you can install it through **command line**, so you will not get any error template related!

**Thanks, this will help you out.**

Comment: Thanks , this will save my day ...:)

Comment: you are welcome, can you please up the vote, as this will helpful for others also, Thanks